# Implement IOS 7 zoom-in, zoom-out transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I want to implement the zoom-in zoom-out transitions in my ios app's main screen, just like the transitions in ios7 app launcher.

I am not sure if I am on the right path, but i created `UIScrollView` in my main screen , and created the buttons within the scroll view. I passed the rect frame of one of the buttons to `zoomToRect` but no zooming took place.

My Plan is to transition into another view of my app along with the zoom-in animation on button which fills the screen.

Am I missing something in the usage of `UIScrollView` with `zoomToRect` or am I completely wrong in using a scroll view for the main screen.  I was able to achieve Zoom-in effect by using `UIView` as my app's main screen and then scaling it with `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` transformation.

Answer (score 0):

1.On your stroryboard place the uiscrollView on the view controller.
2.Place the uiimageView on the uiscrollView
3.Make sure your stroryboard is not on autolayout.
4.On your show size inspector make sure you the with and height of the scrollView and the imageView are the same.
5.Make sure the Autosize pins are all clicked.

Go to the UIViewContoller class assigned to the ViewController your working on.

In the Header file add the following properties :

```
         #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

        @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>


        @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView* imageViewPointer;
//Make sure scrollView is linked to the ui element on your storyboard
        @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
//Make sure imageView is linked to the ui element on your storyboard
        @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

        // These properties are new
        @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* imageViewConstraints;
        @property (nonatomic) BOOL imageViewConstraintsNeedUpdating;
        @property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView* scrollViewPointer;

    //Then in the implementation file this the following code to implement

    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    @synthesize scrollView,imageView;

    - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    {
        return self.imageViewPointer;
    }



    - (void)scrollViewWillBeginZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view
    {
        if(_imageViewConstraintsNeedUpdating)
        {
            // Remove the previous image view constraints
            [self.view removeConstraints:_imageViewConstraints];

            // Replace them with new ones, this time constraining against the width & height of the scroll view's content, not the scroll view itself
            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_scrollViewPointer, _imageViewPointer);
            [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_imageViewPointer(width)]|" options:0 metrics:@{@"width" : @(_scrollViewPointer.contentSize.width)} views:viewsDictionary]];
            [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_imageViewPointer(height)]|" options:0 metrics:@{@"height" : @(_scrollViewPointer.contentSize.height)} views:viewsDictionary]];

            self.imageViewConstraintsNeedUpdating = NO;
        }
    }



    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your Image"]];

        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

       scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

        self.imageViewPointer = imageView;

        // New
        self.scrollViewPointer = scrollView;
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5;
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
        scrollView.delegate = self;

        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView, imageView);
        NSLog(@"Current views dictionary: %@", viewsDictionary);
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];

        // Saving the image view width & height constraints
        self.imageViewConstraints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        // Constrain the image view to be the same width & height of the scroll view
        [_imageViewConstraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[imageView(scrollView)]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
        [_imageViewConstraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[imageView(scrollView)]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];

        // Add the image view constraints to the VIEW, not the scroll view
        [self.view addConstraints:_imageViewConstraints];

        // Flag
        self.imageViewConstraintsNeedUpdating = YES;


    }

    @end
```

Comment: After having a look at the following answer(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184619/how-can-i-animate-zoom-in-zoom-out-on-ios-using-objective-c) I was able to implement it to solve your problem.