# Animating UIButton to zoom in and out on click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I got a button that I've replaced with an icon and when the icon is clicke I want it to zoom in and out for lets say 5 seconds. How can I accomplish this? I have made a set of 5 images with different sizes for the button, can I loop thru theese or is there an other way?

```
@IBAction func myButton(sender: UIButton){
    //animation that zoom the button icon in and out
}
```

Edit: Im using Xcode 6.4

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184619/how-can-i-animate-zoom-in-zoom-out-on-ios-using-objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will zoom in and out the button without using additional images:

```
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "stopButtonAnimation", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0, options: options, 
animations: {
    self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5)
}, completion:nil)
```

.....

```
func stopButtonAnimation() {
    button.layer.removeAllAnimations;
}
```

Comment: Do I put this in my IBAction function?

Comment: @TheDude yes, you should

Comment: This is great! Is it possible to make this loop on for a set duration?

Comment: @TheDude I update my answer with the right duration, my bad! If it helps you please mark my answer as right, I would appreciate it, thanks :)

Comment: Well, the first duration with 0.25 was perfect, but I want it to repeat the in and out for a set time if you know what I mean?

Comment: @TheDude I updated my answer, let me know if it works for you

Comment: Gettin a couple errors, is the #selector supposed to be altered?

Comment: @TheDude yep, you should change MyClass with the your class name, what are the other errors?

Comment: I get "expected ',' seperator after 'selector:' and the same after 'completion: nil'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120948/discussion-between-saintthread-and-the-dude).

Answer (score 9):

To show an alternative, I will show an approach with animating Layers.
More infos about it [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/animations-explained/)

**Add this code to your function (hints are in the code comments):**

```
// specify the property you want to animate
let zoomInAndOut = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
// starting from the initial value 1.0
zoomInAndOut.fromValue = 1.0
// to scale down you set toValue to 0.5
zoomInAndOut.toValue = 0.5
// the duration for the animation is set to 1 second
zoomInAndOut.duration = 1.0
// how many times you want to repeat the animation
zoomInAndOut.repeatCount = 5
// to make the one animation(zooming in from 1.0 to 0.5) reverse to two animations(zooming back from 0.5 to 1.0)
zoomInAndOut.autoreverses = true
// because the animation consists of 2 steps, caused by autoreverses, you set the speed to 2.0, so that the total duration until the animation stops is 5 seconds
zoomInAndOut.speed = 2.0
// add the animation to your button
button.layer.addAnimation(zoomInAndOut, forKey: nil)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Better approach!